# How to compare variable to text in unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, comparison, uname

I've tried many version of this but none of them work.I want to compare variable - here it'll be version of os, with some string. I want to check if it is bigger than indicated version. When I pass exact name it is just fine, but when I want to replace something with .* it doesn't work.

```
if [[ "$(uname -r)" == '3\.18.*' ]];

then echo bravo;

fi
```

how to make it work? thanks in advance

Comment: Read the manual on the [`[[`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) operator.  You need the trailing `.*` outside of quotes, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a case statement here:

```
case $(uname -r) in
(3.18.*) echo bravo;;
esac
```

If you want to check if the version is larger than some value or not, you might use something like:

```
case $(uname -r) in
(3.1[89].*|3.[2-9]*|[4-9]*) echo bravo;;
(*) echo alpha;;
esac
```

Comment: That's very much the classic way to do it, and it is pretty much unambiguous too.